# How do I check if a key exists in Memcache (AWS Elastic Cache instance) using python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, caching, memcached

I'm trying to create a dynamic query which will be a part of memcache key. Is there any way to lookup keys in the memcache? I'm trying to acheive this because if there is any way, I would first lookup in that keymap and will create a new key only if it doesn't exist.

I'm using python + Pymemcache module.

Comment: http://pymemcache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#basic-usage, have you not looked at the page?

Comment: Yes, I checked that. It wasn't helpful.

Comment: Downvoted, as this is present as very basic documentation of memcache.

Comment: Well, there's no need to be that pathetic. I don't think it is there in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevertheless, I found one simple way to check that. So, posting it as an answer.

```
if client.get(key) is None:
    //your_code
```